# What is this material under car carpet, can I remove it?

Tags: body

[image]

Here is a pic of underneath my car carpet (civic vti 1999).  I was thinking of getting rid of the carpet however I noticed a black rubber type material which gives off it’s own smell.  I notice this material also exists in the boot.

I was actually wanting to remove the carpet because divers hold on to smells and I don’t like smells.  I guess if I remove the carpet I will have to live with this material.  What is it and what is it’s purpose, is there a way I can remove it and if I do so, will there be a problem?

A friend looked at the material in the boot and said it is to do with chassis protection, any truth in that?

Comment: Just remove carpet and power wash it. Use soap and broom or somethig to scrub it if power washing isnt enough then leave in sun for a day or two to dry. should get rid of old smells and then you can just put it back in.

Comment: I think @narkeleptk is saying to power wash the carpet ... don't try that with the inside of the car.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did indeed mean remove and power wash the carpet.

Comment: It looks like an oil has soaked through the carpet and partially liquefied the original  coating.

Comment: @blacksmith37 thats water which has leaked in.

Answer (score 2):

That is an underlay to help deaden sound and also panel vibration. It may also be an insulator.

If you remove it then the noise level will increase and perhaps you will also get panel vibrations...

Comment: Plus, I'm not even sure _how_ you would remove it.  Not something I would try.

Comment: @JPhi1618 if you need to weld the panel it has to come off - knife and scraper...